# Estimote : Show notification when the app is closed

Tags: notifications, android, estimote

How to show notification when the app is closed with estimote api.As it is having default BeaconService we need to implement it in the application level to show the notification when the app is closed.So for that i'm trying with the following code.

Activity:-

```
public class Dashboard extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = Dashboard.class.getSimpleName();
ConnectionDetector cDetector;
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 123;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

AlertDialogManager alert;
private static final String URL_NOTIFICATIONS = "";
ArrayList<NameValuePair> pairs;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1234;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private BeaconManager bManager;
// private Beacon beacon;
private Region region = new Region("regionID", null, null, null);
List<Beacon> beaconList;

BroadcastReceiver receiver;
Intent serviceIntent;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notify_demo);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    cDetector = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // check Internet connection
    if (!cDetector.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        alert.showAlertDialog(this, "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working internet connection", false);

        return;
    }

    bManager = new BeaconManager(getApplicationContext());
    bManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region,
                final List<Beacon> beacons) {
            // Note that results are not delivered on UI thread.
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Note that beacons reported here are already sorted by
                    // estimated distance between device and beacon.
                    getActionBar().setSubtitle(
                            "Found beacons: " + beacons.size());

                }
            });
        }
    });
    Log.i("BeaconsList", "beaconslist" + beaconList);
    // region = new Region("regionId", ((Beacon)
    // beaconList).getProximityUUID(),
    // ((Beacon) beaconList).getMajor(),
    // ((Beacon) beaconList).getMinor());
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Default values are 5s of scanning and 25s of waiting time to save CPU
    // cycles.In order for this demo to be more responsive and immediate we
    // lower down those values.
    bManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1), 0);



    bManager.setMonitoringListener(new MonitoringListener() {

        @Override
        public void onEnteredRegion(Region arg0, List<Beacon> arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postNotification("Welcome to Walmart !Today there is 10% off on all Goods.");
            // new GetNotificationData().execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void onExitedRegion(Region arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postNotification("Exit region");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Check if device supports Bluetooth Low Energy.
    if (!bManager.hasBluetooth()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Device does not have Bluetooth Low Energy",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    // If Bluetooth is not enabled, let user enable it.
    if (!bManager.isBluetoothEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
                BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    } else {
        connectToService();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    try {
        bManager.stopRanging(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error while stopping ranging", e);
    }

    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            connectToService();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            getActionBar().setSubtitle("Bluetooth not enabled");
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void connectToService() {
    getActionBar().setSubtitle("Scanning...");

    bManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceReady() {
            try {
                bManager.startRanging(region);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        Dashboard.this,
                        "Cannot start ranging, something terrible happened",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot start ranging", e);
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    bManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceReady() {
            try {
                bManager.startMonitoring(region);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error while starting monitoring");
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    bManager.disconnect();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void postNotification(String msg) {
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, Dashboard.class);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(
            Dashboard.this, 0, new Intent[] { notifyIntent },
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(Dashboard.this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.beacon_gray)
            .setContentTitle("Notify Demo").setContentText(msg)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    TextView statusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
    statusTextView.setText(msg);
}
}
```

Application Class:-

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

BeaconManager bManager;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
private Region region = new Region("regionID", null, null, null);
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 123;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    bManager = new BeaconManager(getApplicationContext());

    bManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region regions, List<Beacon> beacons) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Beacons", "" + beacons.size());
        }
    });
    bManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceReady() {
            try {
                bManager.startMonitoring(region);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.d("BEACON", "Error while starting monitoring");
            }
        }
    });

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Default values are 5s of scanning and 25s of waiting time to save CPU
    // cycles.In order for this demo to be more responsive and immediate we
    // lower down those values.
    bManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1), 0);


    bManager.setMonitoringListener(new MonitoringListener() {

        @Override
        public void onEnteredRegion(Region arg0, List<Beacon> arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postNotification("Welcome to Walmart !Today there is 10% off on all Goods.");

        }

        @Override
        public void onExitedRegion(Region arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postNotification("Exit region");
        }
    });

}

private void postNotification(String msg) {
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            Dashboard.class);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(
            getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent[] { notifyIntent },
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(
            getApplicationContext()).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.beacon_gray)
            .setContentTitle("Notify Demo").setContentText(msg)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

}
}
```

and i have mentioned the beaconservice in manifest also as follows..

Can any one help what is going wrong here and how can show the notification when the app is closed.